# indexoutofrangeexception in Datatable with Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, datatable, parallel-processing, sqlbulkcopy, parallel.foreach

I am trying to augment a DataTable that has IP addresses in one column with their reverse dns mapping. I am getting this DataTable from somewhere else. I am then exporting this table to SQL Server using SQLBulkcopy

I am adding two columns, one for the dns name and one for the top level domain part only. SInce I have a lot of IPs and doing reverse DNS takes some time I am using a Parallel for each. 
Strangely I get odd unpredictable IndexOutOfRangeExceptions within NestedException for the parallel loop (or sometimes outside of the parallel loop when I call clear in the datatable). Why?

Here is what I am doing

```
        //mapping specifies a mapping within the DataTable and the Database

        SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> pair in mapping)
        {                                                                       
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }


        dt.Columns.Add("URL");
        dt.Columns.Add("Domain");
        solver.AddDNSInfo(dt, 1); //second row has the IP
        copy.WriteToServer(dt);
        dt.Clear();     //exceptions are thrown here   




    //ipIndex is the index within the datatable where the IP of interest is. 
    //In my scenario ipIndex=1
    public void AddDNSInfo(DataTable table, int ipIndex)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(table.AsEnumerable(), row =>
        {
                string URL = GetDNSName((string)row[ipIndex]);
                row["URL"] = URL; //exceptions are thrown here
                row["Domain"] = GetTopLevelDomain(URL);
                Console.Write("*");
        });
```

Comment: it look like you haven't added any row to your datatable

Comment: I get dt from another part of the program that loads data from a text file. I will add it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `DataTable` is not thread safe for multithreaded write operation.

**[MSDN says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)**

> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations.

You are writing new columns with multiple threads at the same time when, in your `Parallel.ForEach`, you do :

```
  row["URL"] = URL;
  row["Domain"] = GetTopLevelDomain(URL);
```

You need to synchronize any writing call to your `DataTable` (using a lock, or some form of monitor)

Comment: Yeah.That totally fixed it.
Thanks!